# CORS policy blocking localhost application but not Postman

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm attempting to setup API management and the first step is to have Oauth configured on an API Management instance.  [Edit] It might be important to mention that the client app has no interest in authenticating users - I'm just looking to use this as an authorization mechanism for a client app and and API app.

I have a CORS policy on my Inbound that looks like this:

```
<cors allow-credentials="true">
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>http://localhost:4200</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>content-type</header>
            <header>accept</header>
        </allowed-headers>
    </cors>
```

I can hit the Token endpoint and get an access token back using Postman on my local (which I'd expect would not be allowed given the allowed-origins configuration:

[image]

The same request from an Angular application running on localhost:4200 is blocked by CORS:

[image]

I've read everything I can about configuring API Management to handle CORS but I'm stuck.  What am I doing wrong?

Because I might be doing something wrong in Angular, here is my call:

```
const config = environment.authConfig;
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('grant_type', config.grantType)
  .set('client_id', config.clientId)
  .set('scope', config.scope)
  .set('client_secret', config.clientSecret);
let options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
}
return this.http.post<Auth0AccessResponse>(config.tokenUrl, body.toString(), options);
```

[image]

Comment: First of all put * on header or include all the header which passed while request comes in.

Comment: I did try that - I put * on allowed headers, allowed methods, and allowed origins.  I'm beginning to believe this is being blocked by chrome because Azure isn't adding the CORS headers

Comment: Where did you set your policy?  I mean which level?

Comment: The policy is set in API management in the Inbound Processing section

Comment: I mean is it on product levels, API or Operation levels? If inside in product level then you have to pass product subscription key on query parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, unfortunately. I added two app registrations (api and client) and then, in API Management I went to API, selected the only API I have, and added the CORS policy to the Inbound Processing.  I followed these instructions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: Ah...not this steps actually, problem encounter on your APIM policy settings, I need that information. If you go to portal you could see in APIM there are product and API menu where did you set policy? If API then is it global or any specific API then I can provide you the solution. Other than solution might not be specific to your issue. Hope you got my point. All I need where did you set policy and how do you send request that's it if possible include that information on your question. One more thing is it working if you get rid of auth part?

Comment: I added another screenshot - hopefully that answers your question.   I'm now considering an alternate route to manage authorization for this SPA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702155/restrict-access-of-an-app-service-so-that-it-is-only-accessible-by-another-app-s

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I too am facing exact issue?